how to customize all-auth errors for mismatch passwords to othere languge?
class PasswordVerificationMixin(object):
    def clean(self):
        cleaned_data = super(PasswordVerificationMixin, self).clean()
        password1 = cleaned_data.get("password1")
        password2 = cleaned_data.get("password2")
        if (password1 and password2) and password1 != password2:
            self.add_error("password2", _("You must type the same password each time."))
        return cleaned_data

I want to override this class and make the error message to 'this a test'
i am stuck i tried overriding it but nothing any help?
